# Append to a text file via batch script does not work

Tags: batch-file, cmd

All,

Here is my code to create a cfg file via batch scripting. It adds the first line but does not append anything after that.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a IN ('TYPE !oTcPath!') DO (

        ECHO.//!site!~!cluster!> "!vPath!\tc.cfg"
        IF !c! == 1 (
            echo h
            SET tmp=%%a=tc/!hname!          
            ECHO !tmp! >> "!vPath!\tc.cfg"      
        )

        IF !c! == 2 (
            SET tmp=%%a=!site!
            ECHO.!tmp!>> "!vPath!\tc.cfg"
        )

        IF !c! == 3 (
            SET tmp=%%a=!cluster!
            ECHO.!tmp!>> "!vPath!\tc.cfg"
        )

        SET /a c=!c!+1
    )
```

but when i do the same via `cmd` it works fine. It appends to the same file nicely.

Comment: I do not see delayed expansion enabled.  Nor do you set your **c** variable until the end of your loop.  It looks to me like it should at least be initialized to zero before the FOR command.

Comment: Every iteration of your FOR command will wipe out your cfg file because you are just using one redirection symbol. `ECHO.//!site!~!cluster!> "!vPath!\tc.cfg"`

Comment: Thanks for the fastest response! I did enabled it at the top of my code and i have set c to 1. It's actually entering the if blocks and echoes any tmp messages except the append part.

Comment: Man! I am the dumb guy! I just realized it! Thank you !

Comment: Sometimes your eyes play tricks on you.  I have made plenty of bone headed mistakes in my I.T. career.

Comment: @Mofi - I think you might mean `SET /A c+=1`.

Comment: Yes, `SET /a c=!c!+1` is better coded with `SET /A c+=1`. In an arithmetic expression environment variables must not be expanded at all. Windows command interpreter access automatically the current value of the environment variable. And using operator `+=` is a little bit faster for incrementing value of a variable.

Comment: Thanks guys! yes, I changed the code to /A. '/a' wont work by the way!